# How to 3D plot a loss function with y, x1 and x2, with no beta0?

Tags: plot, 3d

I am not sure how to plot the MSE function (loss function) on a 3D plot with the variables (y,x1 and x2). The below portion is what I have tried. b1 and b2 are beta 1 and beta 2.

```
 def MSE (y, x1, x2):
      MSE = np.square(np.subtract(y,b1x1,b2x2)).mean() 

 for i in range(0,506): 
      b1=i
      b2=i
```

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried? What language are you using? what framework?

Comment: def MSE (y, x1, x2):
    MSE = np.square(np.subtract(y,b1x1,b2x2)).mean() 
       
for i in range(0,506): 
        b1=i
        b2=i

Comment: Im using python